# Get rid of duplicates in array of objects

Tags: javascript, arrays

I'm trying to get rid of duplicates in array of objects. I want my code linear so I'm using hashtable:

```
output = Array.from(new Set(output.map(e => e.company)))
  .map(company => { return output.find(e => e.company === company) })
```

This code works properly for this array of objects:

```
let output = [
  { company: 'sony'},
  { company: 'sony'},
  { company: 'apple'}
]
```

but thing is that I want to reuse this code so I would like to move it to function which would take array `output` and `company` string. I don't know how to do that, I tried like this:

```
const uniq = (array, key) => {
  return Array.from(new Set(array.map( e => e[key] )))
    .map(key => { return array.find(e => e[key] === key) })
}
```

but this return array of two undefined.

---

Also second thing is that it's pretty complicated code for such trivial task. Isn't there some easier way to do same without losing performance?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This one-liner works with arbitrary objects, not necessarily key:value pairs:

```js
let uniqBy = (a, key) => [...new Map(a.map(x => [x[key], x]).reverse()).values()];

//

let data = [
    {company: 'sony', more: 1},
    {company: 'apple', more: 1},
    {company: 'sony', more: 2},
    {company: 'sony', more: 3},
    {company: 'apple', more: 3},
]

console.log(uniqBy(data, 'company'))
```

If you don't care about the order of the result, you can also skip `.reverse()`.

Comment: I think this and @Nina Scholz are my personal favourite solutions

Comment: Also it looks like it's just slightly faster but rather insignificant https://jsperf.com/filter-arr-of-obj-2/1

Answer (score 2):

You could map the unique values and create a new object.

```js
const 
    unique = (array, key) => Array.from(new Set(array.map(o => o[key])), value => ({ [key]: value }));

var output = [{ company: 'sony'}, { company: 'sony'}, { company: 'apple'}];

console.log(unique(output, "company"));
```

Answer (score 1):

You have naming conflicts, just rename the second `key`:

```js
let input = [{ company: "sony" }, { company: "sony" }, { company: "apple" }];

const uniq = (array, key) => {
  return Array.from(new Set(array.map(e => e[key]))).map(key1 => {
    //                                                   ^^^^
    return array.find(e => e[key] === key1);
    //                                ^^^^
  });
};

const result = uniq(input, "company");

console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 1):

I think the issue is you are overwriting the definition of `key` in the `.map()` callback. This version - with a separate variable name for the callback parameter -  seems to do what you need:

```js
let output = [
  { company: 'sony'},
  { company: 'sony'},
  { company: 'apple'}
]
const uniq = (array, key) => {
  return Array.from(new Set(array.map( e => e[key] )))
    .map(x => { return array.find(e => e[key] === x) })
}

console.log(uniq(output, "company"));
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to rename your second `map` parameter to something other than `key`, otherwise the `key` inside find will not be the parameter `key` that is passed to the function:

```js
let output = [
  { company: 'sony'},
  { company: 'sony'},
  { company: 'apple'}
]

const uniq = (array, key) => {
  return Array.from(new Set(array.map( e => e[key] )))
    .map(k => { return array.find(e => e[key] === k) })
}

console.log(uniq(output, 'company'));
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are allowed to use Lodash there is a simple way of eliminating duplicates

```
_.uniqBy(your_data, 'company');
```